# categoryChoiceTree in prestashop module configuration page

Tags: php, module, tree, prestashop

I'm developing a prestashop module and I'm trying to show a category tree in my backoffice configuration page.

I'm trying to follow this instructions below but  I don't know exactly where to add [this code.](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/form/types-reference/category-choice-tree/)

It should be inside main module's php? or inside a separate .php file and call it from the main one (don't know how to do it either).

As much time I'm spending trying to figure out, how to implement the code in the link above, the more I think I'm losing my time.
I see that "use" files, and this JS, " /admin-dev/themes/new-theme/js/components/form/choice-tree.js " are not in any prestashop folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is SOLVED!!!! Finally it was very simple, but you must get the correct info for you particular case.
@Robertino's answer might be the best implementation, I don't know, but it became impossible to solve for me,

I uses this code below, and called $categoryTree from the form input. This input must be type=> categories_select

Thanks for your time, and for the help of another post from this forum.

```
$root = Category::getRootCategory();

    //Generating the tree
    $tree = new HelperTreeCategories('categories_1'); //The string in param is the ID used by the generated tree
    $tree->setUseCheckBox(false)
        ->setAttribute('is_category_filter', $root->id)
        ->setRootCategory($root->id)
        ->setSelectedCategories(array((int)Configuration::get('CATEGORY_1'))) //if you wanted to be pre-carged
        ->setInputName('CATEGORY_1'); //Set the name of input. The option "name" of $fields_form doesn't seem to work with "categories_select" type
    $categoryTree = $tree->render();
```

And the Form:

```
                    array(
                    'type'  => 'categories_select',
                    'label' => $this->l('Category'),
                    'desc' => $this->l('Select Category '),
                    'name'  => 'CATEGORY_1', //No ho podem treure si no, no passa la variable al configuration
                    'category_tree'  => $categoryTree, //This is the category_tree called in form.tpl
                    'required' => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should invest some time and learn Symfony since this is what you need to build backend modules for Prestashop 1.7.

As a pointer, you need to create a form class extending the CommonAbstractType, add a build form method. e.g. :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->context = Context::getContext();
        $parents = [
          ['id_category' => 2, 'name' => 'Home', 'children' => $this->getSubCategories(1, true, 2)]
        ];

        $builder->add('category', CategoryChoiceTreeType::class, [
            'choices_tree' => $parents,
            'choice_value' => 'id_category',
            'choice_children' => 'children',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'disabled_values' => $disabledCategories,
            'label' => 'Choose a category'
        ])
```

then add methods for retrieving the data to populate the form fields.

Then use this class in your controller and display the form:

```
$form = $this->createForm(YourFormForm::class);
```

Also add a processForm to process data.

As mentioned, this is not a copy/paste situation you need to understand the Symfony workflow.

Comment: Hi Robertino, this is what I'm actually doing but I find some differences between symfony and prestashop backoffice that are difficult to understand, if you are a noob,

Comment: Hi Pol, I understand and it is only normal to feel frustrated when starting on a new tech, it happens to all of us. However what I have exemplified above works for me in a PS1.7.6+ backend module using Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I found to "paint" the categorytree in my configuration page is adding this code to the inputs form array:

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve users selection data to my database?
It does not work as any other form field.

```
array(
                            'type' => 'categories',
                            'label' => $this->l('Destination Category'),
                            'desc' => $this->l('Select ONE Category'),
                            'name' => 'CATEGORY_CATEGORY_TO',
                            'tree' => [
                                // 'selected_categories' => [],
                                'disabled_categories' => null,
                                'use_search' => false,
                                'use_checkbox' => false,
                                'id' => 'id_category_tree',
                            ],
                            'required' => true
                        ),
```